# How to write an arraylist as a CSV

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, opencsv

I currently have the arraylist from the resultset and I use openCSV library to print as a CSV.

```
ArrayList<Integer> arlist=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(i=1;i<30;i++){
 for(k=1;k<100;k++){

       String sql="select count(id) where day=?"
       PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       pstmt.setInt(1,k);
       ResultSet rs=rs.getInt(1);
       int count=rs.getInt(1); 
       arlist.add(count);
   }


   CSVWriter writer=new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/home/user/file"+i+".csv"),',')
   writer.writeNext(arlist.toArray(new String [0]));
   writer.close();
   arlist.clear();
}
```

But the problem is the CSV is a 1 line CSV with 100 columns.Instead  of this I need a 100 line CSV with 1 column.(size of array list is 100).Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: What is `supply` ? Also, please, try to create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like each array you pass to `writeNext()` becomes a single row in the CSV, so you need a loop that calls `writeNext()` for each element of your `List` :

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/home/user/file" + i + ".csv"),',') ;
for (Integer i : arlist) {
    writer.writeNext(new String[]{i.toString()});
}
writer.close();
arlist.clear();
```

Of course, since you only have one column in each line, you can skip using that `CSVWriter` class and just dump each element of the `List` to a separate line of the output file.

Comment: arlist is a Integer array list and how can u loop by a String?

Comment: The method 'writeNext' allows only String[ ] as it's argument

Comment: @RKR OK, in that case, converting each Integer of the List to a String[] will work. I did fix another typo.

Comment: I used the above method but did not work.i also tried `for (Integer i : arlist) {  String [] y=new String[1];
    y[0]=x.toString();writer.writeNext(new String[]{i.toString()});
}`But did not work

Comment: @RKR What output do you get?

Comment: Yeah which I commented above worked.The problem was which I had the writer.writeNext two times.Now it worked like a charm